# Alignment in ListViewItem using DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, listview, alignment, datatemplate, listviewitem

I'm using a ListView to show person first name and last name.
I want to align the first name to the left and the last name to the right

I wrote the following code:

```
<Windows.Resources>
  <DataTemplate Datatype="{x:Type local:Person}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontel">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" TextAlignment="Left">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" TextAlignment="Right">
  </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplates>
</Windows.Resources>

<ListView Name="myList", ItemSource="{Binding}" />
```

The ListView.DataContext connected to ObservableCollection

The result is that both first name and last name align to the left.
I also tried to use DockPanel([How to make DockPanel fill available space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080479/how-to-make-dockpanel-fill-available-space))
but it doesnt work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this post: [https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10765652/how-to-right-align-content-in-a-datatemplate][]

```
<Windows.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
  <Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
     <ColumDefinition Width="*" />
     <ColumDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinition>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Grid.Column="0">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" Grid.Column="1">
 </Grid>
 </DataTemplates>
</Windows.Resources>

<ListView Name="myList", ItemSource="{Binding}" HorzintalContentAlignment="Strech" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DockPanel for it

```
 <Windows.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
  <DockPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"  HorizontalAlignemnt="Left">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" HorizontalAlignemnt="Right">
 </DockPanel>
 </DataTemplates>
 </Windows.Resources>

  <ListView Name="myList", ItemSource="{Binding}" HorzintalContentAlignment="Strech" />
```